# How many days in a row can a Canadian citizen stay in the US?

Tags: visas, usa, us-visa-waiver-program, canadian-citizens

I've been in the US for a few months and I just realized I don't know process of what happens if you stay longer. I flew to the US one-way and wasn't too sure when I was returning. How many months can a Canadian stay in the US before having to leave and come back and how does one get permission to stay longer?

Comment: The second sentence looks a bit weird and is hard to read.

Comment: Did you check for a stamp in your passport?  It may give the validity date.

Comment: @Nate: Kind of misplaced it right now.

Comment: There are at least two different durations to consider: One for US immigration, and another for tax.  Make sure you check them both in detail for your situation so you aren't surprised later.  For example, the IRS can consider you a US tax resident (so you have to file US tax) in advance of the INS objecting to your presence.

Answer (score 6):

Canadians can stay up to six months from the entry date before they need to leave the US and re-enter. If you want to stay longer you can request an extension, from the Visa Waiver Program [official page](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/194/kw/):

> If you are from Canada, the length of stay for tourism is up to 6 months. Canadians may file for an extension of stay with the U.S. Citizenship and Immigration Services.

Comment: Waiver program? What if you entered without a Visa?

Comment: Hmm, so you must apply even if you didn't enter with one?  Is it a long process or will stepping out of the border for 10 minutes and waltzing back in be more efficient?

Comment: @verve: Well, keep in mind that if you leave, there's no guarantee you'll be allowed back in.

Comment: @verve Waiver program is entering without visa..

Comment: Why is Canada un listed under the Waiver program?  It says if you're visiting under a waiver stay you CANNOT apply..huh?!

Comment: @Nate: do they usually renew it easily if you are just a tourist?  Why are media people held to a different set of rules?

Comment: @verve: Sorry, I don't know how renewals are usually handled.  I just wanted to point out there is the possibility it would not be renewed, or not right away.  (And I'm not sure what "media people" have to do with this; are you one?)

Comment: The link you've posted doesn't appear to contain the quoted text.

Comment: @michael the link I posted 3 years ago...